# Slow OMP vs serial

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, openmp, slowdown

I'm trying to optimize a C subroutine called from R that takes up ~60% of the computation time for a problem I'm trying to solve. This is down from 86% when coded purely in R. The vast majority of the execution time in my C code is taking place in a nested for loop and so this seems an obvious candidate to try and parallelize using OpenMP. I've tried doing so with variable results – at best the elapsed time is fractionally worse than not using OMP, at worst the performance scaled inversely to the number of threads. The code for the fastest version is below:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <omp.h>
void gradNegLogLik_c(double *param, double *delta, double *X, double *M, int *nBeta, int *nEpsilon, int *nObs, double *gradient){
  // ========================================================================================
  // param:     double[nBeta + nEpsilon]        values of parameters at which to evaluate gradient
  // delta:     double[nObs]                    satellite - buoy differences
  // X:         double[nObs * (nBeta + nEpsilon)]  design matrix for mean components (i.e. beta terms)
  // M:         double[nObs * (nBeta + nEpsilon)]  design matrix for variance components (i.e. epsilon terms)
  // nBeta:     int                             number of mean terms
  // nEpsilon:  int                             number of variance terms
  // nObs:      int                             number of observations
  // gradient:  double[nBeta + nEpsilon]        output array of gradients
  // ========================================================================================

  // ========================================================================================
  // local variables
  size_t i, j, ind;
  size_t nterms = *nBeta + *nEpsilon;  
  size_t nbeta  = *nBeta;
  size_t nepsilon  = *nEpsilon;
  size_t nobs = *nObs; 
  // allocate local memory and set to zero
  double *sigma2        = calloc( nobs     , sizeof(double) );
  double *fittedValues  = calloc( nobs     , sizeof(double) );
  double *residuals     = calloc( nobs     , sizeof(double) );
  double *beta          = calloc( nbeta    , sizeof(double) );
  double *epsilon2      = calloc( nepsilon , sizeof(double) );  
  double *residuals2    = calloc( nobs     , sizeof(double) );
  double gradBeta, gradEpsilon;

  // extract beta and epsilon terms from param
  // =========================================
  for(i = 0 ; i < nbeta ; i++){
    beta[i]    = param[ i ];
    epsilon2[i] = param[ nbeta + i ];
  }

  // Initialise gradient to zero for return value
  // =========================================  
  for( i = 0 ; i < nterms ; i++){
    gradient[i] = 0;
  }

  // calculate sigma, fitted values and residuals
  // ============================================  
  for( i = 0 ; i < nbeta ; i++){
    for( j = 0 ; j < nobs ; j++){
      ind = i * nobs + j;
      sigma2[j] += M[ind] * epsilon2[i];
      fittedValues[j] += X[ind] * beta[i];
    }
  }

  for( j = 0 ; j < nobs ; j++){
    // calculate reciprocal as this is what we actually use and 
    // we only want to do it once.        
    sigma2[j] = 1 / sigma2[j]; 
    residuals[j] = delta[j] - fittedValues[j];    
    residuals2[j] = residuals[j]*residuals[j];
  } 

  // Loop over all observations and calculate value of (negative) derivative  
  // =======================================================================    
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, ind, gradBeta, gradEpsilon)\
  shared(gradient, nbeta, nobs, X, M, sigma2, fittedValues, delta, residuals2) \
  default(none) 
  for( i = 0 ; i < nbeta ; i++){
    gradBeta = 0.0;
    gradEpsilon = 0.0;
    for(j = 0 ; j < nobs ; j++){
      ind = i * nobs + j;
      gradBeta    -= -1.0*X[ind] * sigma2[j]*(fittedValues[j] - delta[j]);
      gradEpsilon -= 0.5*M[ind] * sigma2[j]*(residuals2[j] * sigma2[j] - 1);
    }
    gradient[i] = gradBeta;
    gradient[nbeta + i] = gradEpsilon;
  }

  // End of function
  // free local memory
  free(sigma2);
  free(fittedValues);
  free(residuals);
  free(beta);
  free(epsilon2);
  free(residuals2);
}
```

nObs is order 10000.

nBeta is in the range 20 – several hundred.

nEpsilon = nBeta and is not currently used.

After searching through this site and an afternoon googling and trying different things I don't seem to be able to make any further improvement. My first thoughts were false sharing – I've tried various things such as unrolling the outer loop to set 8 elements of gradient[] at a time to creating a temporary padded array to store the results in. I've also tried different combinations of shared, private and firstprivate. None of this appears to improve things and my fastest execution time is marginally worse in parallel than in serial. This leads to two questions before I spend any more time on this:

- Is my problem (repeating ~9000 of the same set of calculations 20 - 900 times) too small to make it worthwhile using OMP?
- Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

I suspect it's the latter as I'm relatively inexperienced when using C and OMP. Any help / thoughts would be appreciated.

(For info, I'm running on SLED11 server with 16 cores and 192GB of memory and using GCC 4.7.2 to compile my C code). Other users are using the server but the relative performance of OMP vs serial code seems independent of the other users.

Thanks in advance,

Dave.

EDIT: For info the compile command I've used is

```
gcc -I/RHOME/R/3.0.1/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -fpic \
    -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic –O3 -fopenmp -c src/gradNegLogLik_call.c \
     -o src/gradNegLogLik_call.o
```

Most of the flags are set by the `R CMD SHLIB` command - I've added the `-O3 -fopenmp` manually.

Comment: What compiler optimizations are you using? Have you tried `-Ofast -funroll-loops`?

Comment: The range of `nObs` is much larger than `nBeta`. Have you tried parallelizing the inner loop over `j` (you need a reduction on `gradBeta` and `gradEpsilon` to do this) instead of the outer loop over `i`?

Comment: You can also fuse/collapse and parallelize the double loop after `// calculate sigma, fitted values and residuals`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

I've edited above to include the compile command.

Using –Ofast –funroll-loops had little impact. Similar for moving the parallelization inside the outer loop. I really don't how a feel for how OMP parallelizes code – my naïve assumption was that each thread would be assigned a copy of the inner loop to execute, i.e. I would have n threads each performing the inner loop.

Comment: The second comment had me thinking about loop order. Changing this (+ some changes to the R code) has had a significant impact on speed, reducing execution time by 20 – 30 %. Overall I've managed to reduce iteration time from ~1 hour to 3 – 5 minutes by calling C from R and so am going to stop at this point. I'll post an answer below with my revised code.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to give some context to my question above before giving my answer to what I've done to speed up my code (although this has been achieved without using OMP).

My original C function was written to calculate the gradient of a log likelihood function to be used with the R optim() command and the L-BFGS-B method. For each call of optim my log likelihood and gradient functions are each called ~100 times as optim finds the best solution. As a result, these two functions take up the bulk of my execution time, as expected and reported by Rprof, and so were the two targets for converting to C to improve the efficiency of my code.

Converting my two functions to C and optimizing that code has resulted in my calls to optim reducing from an average elapsed time of  1.88s per call to 0.25s per call. This has reduced my processing time from ~1 month to a few days. The change that had the biggest impact (beside calling C) was changing the ordering of the nested loops. The original order was chosen due to the way R stores matrices and chosen to avoid having to transpose my matrices for each call of my C functions.  Recognizing that the transpose only needs to be done once for each call to optim(), and not each C call as I had originally coded, this is a small overhead to pay compared to the impact / benefit of changing the order in the C functions.

Given this increase in speed it's had to justify spending any more time on this. The final version of my gradient function (as per my original post) is given below.

Note that whilst I've changed from using .C to .Call in R (hence the change to the function arguments etc) this in itself doesn’t account for the speed increase.

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <omp.h>
SEXP gradNegLogLik_call(SEXP param ,SEXP delta, SEXP X, SEXP M, SEXP nBeta, SEXP nEpsilon){

  // local variables
  double *par, *d;
  double *sigma2, *fittedValues, *residuals, *grad, *Xuse, *Muse;
  double val, sig2, gradBeta, gradEpsilon;
  int n, m, ind, nterms, i, j;

  SEXP gradient;

  // get / associate parameters with local pointer
  par = REAL(param);
  Xuse = REAL(X);
  Muse = REAL(M);
  d = REAL(delta);
  n = LENGTH(delta);
  m = INTEGER(nBeta)[0];
  nterms = m + m;


  // allocate memory
  PROTECT( gradient = allocVector(REALSXP, nterms ));
  // set pointer to real portion of gradient
  grad = REAL(gradient);

  // set all gradient terms to zero
  for(i = 0 ; i < nterms ; i++){
      grad[i] = 0.0;
  }


  sigma2 = Calloc(n, double );
  fittedValues = Calloc(n, double );
  residuals = Calloc(n, double );

  // calculate sigma, fitted values and residuals
  for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    val = 0.0;
    sig2 = 0.0;
    for(j = 0 ; j < m ; j++){
      ind = i*m + j;
      val +=  Xuse[ind]*par[j];
      sig2 += Muse[ind]*par[j+m];
    }
    // calculate reciprocal of sigma as this is what we actually use
    // and we only want to do it once
    sigma2[i] = 1.0 / sig2;
    fittedValues[i] = val;
    residuals[i] = d[i] - val;
  }


  // now loop over each paramter and calculate derivative
  for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    gradBeta = -1.0*sigma2[i]*(fittedValues[i] - d[i]);
    gradEpsilon = 0.5*sigma2[i]*(residuals[i]*residuals[i]*sigma2[i] - 1);     
    for(j = 0 ; j < m ; j++){
        ind = i*m + j;
        grad[j] -= Xuse[ind]*gradBeta;
        grad[j+m] -= Muse[ind]*gradEpsilon;
    }            
  }

  UNPROTECT(1);
  Free(sigma2);
  Free(residuals);
  Free(fittedValues);
  // return array of gradients  
  return gradient;
}
```

Comment: Note: I had included a padded temporary array (left over from trying to use OMP) in the code above in the false belief that this was slightly quicker based on testing. Testing over a greater number of iterations showed this to be false and has been removed.